# CSS translateX() animation resets whenever mouse stay on element

Tags: css, animation, translate

Hi im working on a CSS only animation and I need to make a block appear on a card here the 0% and 100% animation transition that activates herself with :hover

[0%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SrjU.png)
[100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDqHn.png)

My need is to make the animation stay on the screen as long as my mouse is on element

TYsm

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far. I suspect the cursor is going out of the element when it moves but cannot know for sure without knowing what you HTML structure and CSS is.

Comment: https://github.com/Betrouni/P3_Betrouni_Nassim

I'm workin on and the site is designed for phone screen

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thx a lot I will, 

just so you know the answer of my question was the parameter :
animation-fill-mode: forwards;

Answer (score 1):

Truing using this code

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div:hover{
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {width: 0%; height:0%}
  to {width: 100%; height: 100%}
}
```